# How do I make a POST request to a different server from my Django-website?

Tags: javascript, django

I have a website running on Django. When a user clicks a submit button, I need to send data to a server running on a different domain and then display the data returned to the user. I can't use an Ajax request because of the cross-domain issue. Lots of sources suggest that I should use Javascript to send to my own server which should then send to the external server, but I don't see how I would implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you submit the URL that the form eventually needs to go to, you can do the processing on the server side. So say you include a hidden field in the form like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_urlfield" value="http://anotherwebsite.com/wheretheformneedstogo">
```

Basically you can do something like:

```
        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://somewhereonthesameserver.com/submit-form',
    data: $('#ajax-form').serialize(),
    success: function(data){...},
            });
```

Then, in the view that corresponds to your submit-form URL:

```
import urllib2
data = urllib2.urlopen(request.POST['form_urlfield'], the_post_data)
//the_post_data is the data that you want to post to the other server..
// do something with the returned data
// return a JSON/Other response
```

Also, make sure you enable the CSRF-Ajax functionality in Django.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-ajax

All of the above is just pseudo-code (I just wrote it out here..) but it should give you an idea on how to proceed. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided by Ashray and dm03514 are correct. But I would perhaps suggest looking at using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) instead of urllib2 for the serverside HTTP handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a http request from your django app.

1. user submits data to django from html form
2. use urllib to send data and get response from other domain
3. submit the appropriate response data to the user.